# Django 4.1.1 ChoiceField widget=forms.RadioSelect label tag missing 'for' attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms, choicefield

I just upgraded from django 2.0.2 to 4.1.1.
I have a few form fields of type ChoiceField with forms.RadioSelect. In django 2.0.2 the  tag included a 'for' attribute/id so I can query in the template
`{% if field.id_for_label == "xyz" %}`. However in 4.1.1 the 'for' attribute/id is not included (when inspecting the html source generated), so field.id_for_label is empty.

All other fields labels still include 'for' attributes/id.

***Questions:***

- Has anyone seen this problem?
- Is there a way to 'force' a 'for' attribute on the labels?
- Is there some other way to identify a field? I tried ...
  `{% if field.label_tag == "label text" %}`, but no good.

Answer (score 0):

@doug-nintzel. Probably i initiated this change in last version of Django.

If i take the radio-widget template code, here:

```
django\forms\templates\django\forms\widgets\radio.html
django\forms\templates\django\forms\widgets\radio-option.html
```

i see, you can use:

```
{% if field.widget.attrs.id == "something" %} ... {% endif %}
```

instead of `field.id_for_label`

Comment: Thanks much Maxim. I tried this out but unfortunately field.widget.attrs.id is empty.
Below is what my radio option files...
=============
cat .local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/radio.html 
{% include "django/forms/widgets/multiple_input.html" %}
cat .local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/radio_option.html
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input_option.html" %}
=========================

Comment: FYI, I found a post for using `{{ field.auto_id }}` to get the field ID and that is working for me....thanks again.